# what does line-to-line mean in webpack configuration?

Tags: webpack, source-maps

[please have a look at this screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMUx0.png)

What does **line-to-line** mean in **webpack**'s configuration for sourcemapping?

Comment: From webpack configuration: Enable line-to-line mapped mode for all/specified modules. Line-to-line mapped mode uses a simple SourceMap where each line of the generated source is mapped to the same line of the original source. It's a performance optimization. Only use it if your performance needs to be better and you are sure that input lines match which generated lines.